# AWS S3 Transfer Utility - How to schedule background upload and overcome the limitations?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-s3

AWS official docs states the following:

> The S3 Transfer Utility generates Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URLs to use for
>   background data transfer. Using Amazon Cognito Identity, you receive
>   AWS temporary credentials that are valid up to 60 minutes. At the same
>   time, generated S3 pre-signed URLs cannot last longer than that time.
>   Because of this limitation, the S3 Transfer Utility enforces 50 minute
>   transfer timeouts, leaving a 10 minute buffer before AWS temporary
>   credentials are regenerated. After 50 minutes, you receive a transfer
>   failure.
>
> If you need to transfer data that cannot be transferred in under 50
>   minutes, use AWSS3 instead.

In my case, I'd like to schedule a background transfer when Wifi is available. This might happen not soon enough though, it's likely that it might exceed 60 minutes validity time.

I wonder if there is any way to handle this problem. Maybe after 60 minutes, system can retry request in some way, or enqueue the session.

How would you approach it? Have any of you faced such problem before and managed to solve it?

Here is my code where I upload the file (note that this is just an example, in default configuration I will send text files ~200mb)

```
func uploadData(data: NSData) {

let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.progressBlock = progressBlock

let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

transferUtility.uploadData(
    data as Data,
    bucket: "test",
    key: "test/test.jpeg",
    contentType: "image/jpeg",
    expression: expression,
    completionHander: completionHandler).continue(successBlock: { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            NSLog("Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);

        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            NSLog("Exception: %@",exception.description);

        }
        if let _ = task.result {

            NSLog("Upload Starting!")
            // Do something with uploadTask.
        }

        return nil;
    })
}
```